# Error Connecting MongoDB in Next JS 13 Application

Tags: database, mongodb, next.js, next.js13

I'm trying to connect MongoDB Atlas with Next.JS (TypeScript) but am unable to connect it. I'm trying it since yesterday and tried a lot of methods but don't know what I'm doing wrong. Every time I request GET/POST it says connection established but then catch blocks run as shown in this [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kIPU.png).

My Code is Given Below:

Connection Code: (It also says in the console **connected**)

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const connectMongo = () => {
  try {
    const mongoURI = process.env.MONGO;
    if (!mongoURI) {
      console.log("mongoURI");
      throw new Error(
        "MongoDB URI not found. Please set the 'MONGO' environment variable."
      ); 
    }
    mongoose.connect(mongoURI);
    console.log("connected");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error");
  }
};
export default connectMongo;
```

My GET & POST API Code:

```
import Post from "@/models/Post";
import dbConnect from "@/utils/db";
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

export const GET = async (request: NextRequest) => {
  try {
    console.log("CONNECTED MONGO");
    await dbConnect();
    console.log("CONNECTED MONGO");
    const posts: any = await Post.find();
    console.log("POSTS Fecthed");
    return NextResponse.json({
      success: posts,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return new NextResponse("DATABASE ERROR", { status: 500 });
  }
};
export const POST = async (request: NextRequest) => {
  const { title, desc, image, username, content } = await request.json();
  try {
    console.log("CONNECTING TO MONGO");
    await dbConnect();
    console.log("CONNECTED TO MONGO");

    console.log("CREATING DOCUMENT");
    const post = await new Post({
      title,
      desc,
      image,
      username,
      content,
    }).save();
    console.log("CREATED DOCUMENT");
    return NextResponse.json({
      success: post,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error");
    console.log(error);
    throw new Error("ERROR");
  }
};
```

Console Error is:

```
> MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/security-whitelist/
    at _handleConnectionErrors (D:\Metaverse\Next JS\fullstack-blog\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:788:11)
    at NativeConnection.openUri (D:\Metaverse\Next JS\fullstack-blog\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:763:11)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async dbConnect (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./utils/db.ts:32:19)
    at async GET (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./app/api/posts/route.ts:15:9)
    at async eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next/dist/server/future/route-modules/app-route/module.js:253:37) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
    servers: Map(3) {
      'ac-lh1wnuj-shard-00-01.ihrszuz.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'ac-lh1wnuj-shard-00-02.ihrszuz.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'ac-lh1wnuj-shard-00-00.ihrszuz.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription]
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: 'atlas-3uuvzc-shard-0',
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined
}
- error Error: ERROR
    at POST (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./app/api/posts/route.ts:50:15)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next/dist/server/future/route-modules/app-route/module.js:253:37)
```

I'm expecting that someone will help mefindg the issue I'm facing.

Comment: What's the error you are getting? Can you log it this way `console.log(error)` and tell us what you get?

Comment: It is updated @YoussoufOumar

Comment: Thanks. Now can you show where you are calling that `connectMongo` function? And also the content of `app/api/posts/route.ts`?

Comment: It is given in the attached picture.
PS: Here I mistakenly renamed ```connectMongo``` with ```connect``` in posts/api.

Comment: Ok I see.  Is the line `50` mentioned in the error message `const posts: any= await Post. findOne()`?

Comment: Now, It is working fine on MongodbCompass locally but not on Atlas.

Comment: Weired. Can you answer my previous question please?

Comment: strange I have only 44 lines of code.
Btw I have update the Questions with ```api/posts/route.ts``` code and ```error```

Comment: I'm asking because I suspect the error is thrown by `Post.findOne()`. Can you try to remove `const posts: any= await Post. findOne()` from the code, and run it?

Comment: same error, not connected to dbConnect and went to else